# node - How to convert MongoDB Timestamp to Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, timestamp

How to convert Mongodb BSON timestamp `new Timestamp()` into native JavaScript `Date` using mongodb node driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The higher 32 bits are a timestamp ([doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)) so you can just do:

```
new Date(timestamp.getHighBits() * 1000)
```

[Driver docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/timestamp.html)

Comment: Thanks. Almost right but you should also multiply it by 1000:
`new Date(timestamp.getHighBits() * 1000)`